# Using AJAX for validation to make sure the same email is not placed in the Data Base

Tags: python, jquery, mysql, flask, partials

I am trying to query the db using `jQuery for validation` to ensure that the same email is not used twice in my application.

1) I am not sure if the `jQuery is correct`. I know it is getting the info from tne input I have targeted with the selector but I am having a problem seeing what is inside the object of what is being sent to the server.

2) The info being sent to the `server is causing a 400 error.
400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.`

-I would like to know how I can access the values being passed in the dictionary.... `request.body.keys() and request.body.values()` did not work. I thought the dictionary I was passing with the , `.ajax() method` would be what is in the `request.body`

-Am I passing the right data by placing the `.serialized()` on the actual input instead of the form as a whole?
I was using the `.serialize() method` on the id for the form initially.

-Is it my MySQL query or how I am passing the dictionary to the string before I send the query? I check MySQL and it queried the email with the code I wrote.

-Is my logic going to work to insert the partial inside of the div? I am not sure if the partial is correct.

```
{% if found == True %}
<p class="error-email">Email has been taken.</p>
{% endif %}
{% if found == False %}
<p class="success-email"> This email is available</p>
{% endif %}
```

-this is the partial HTML code

```
 <div id="email"></div>
 <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="email" id="email-form">
```

*this is the HTML - the div is for the partial when the key up activates the asynchronous code

```
@app.route('/check', methods=["POST"])
def check_avaliability_of_email():
    found = False
    mysql = connectToMySQL('flask_canidate_survey_app')
    query = 'SELECT email FROM flask_canidate_survey_app.users WHERE users.email = "%(check_value)s"'
    print('AJAX_DATA:', request.form.get('email'))
    value_ = data
    check_value = {'user': value_}
    result = mysql.query_db(query, data)
    if result:
        found = True
    return render_template('/partials/validation_email.html', found=found)
```

*the server side code ( python )

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('#email-form').keyup(function() {
        var emailData = $('#email-form').serialize()
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "/check",
            data: emailData
        })
        .done(function(res) {
            $('#email').html(res)
        });
    });
});
```

this is the js/jQuery AJAX call
The result was:

I am getting the 400 error I placed before, and the only thing that prints is Immutable Dictionary.

400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.

Comment: Please add the jquery/ajax code

Comment: Just did, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

The printed Immutable Dictionary is because you're printing the form object, not values. To get actual values use: `request.form.get('email')`.

Also, just noting that you're setting `value_ = data`, where data has not been set, I presume you're wanting to do: `value_ = request.form.get('email')`.

Comment: I want to pass each key that is bring placed inside of the input to the query and use the conditional to print whether or not the value is in the DB. I don't know if I am using the ajax correctly.    `value_ = data
NameError: name 'data' is not defined` this is the error I am getting as soon as I type in the email field.

Comment: Your ajax is serializing the email field only. If you have a form with multiple inputs, you will need to change the serialization to the form itself. That error is expected - as I noted in my answer, you have not declared or set `data`.

Comment: I changed the code above, I think it is what you meant about the object being passed to the .ajax() method.

Comment: The `id` of the email input is `email-form`. If you have other inputs in the form (and want to include these in the POST, remove the id from the input and add it to the `form` tag, e.g. `<form method="POST" action="/check" id="email-form">`

Comment: value_ = data
NameError: name 'data' is not defined is the error I am getting now. What is it in the server side that I am doing wrong? I only want to use the AJAX to check the email, that is why I am using it for the email field.

Comment: I mentioned above you haven't set a value to `data`. Long story short, once your ajax is working, the flask function will receive your email value in `request.form.get('email')` use this to complete your query.